# how to create a custom border in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, widget

I'm trying to create a custom border with a dynamic size and a gradient color on it.

How can I create a border with the same width as the text above?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var selectedItemIndex = 0;

return SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Wrap(
    spacing: 32,
    children: list.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
      var isSelectedItem = (entry.key == selectedItemIndex);
      return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            entry.value,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              color:
                  entry.key == selectedItemIndex ? Colors.white : lightGrey,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 4,
          ),
          Flex(
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: isSelectedItem ? 3 : 2,
                width: 40,  // <- fixed size
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: purpleGradient,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
);
```

}

[image]

ps.: I tried `Flex`, `Flexible`, and `double.infinity` to expand the border's width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

custom button:

```
class UnderlineButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final Function onTap;

  const UnderlineButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.label,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0)),
        ),
        overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color?>(Colors.transparent),
      ),
      onPressed: onTap,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text(label),
          Container(
            height: 7,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                colors: [
                  Colors.blue,
                  Colors.indigo,
                ],
                tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text(label, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.transparent),),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

use custom button in screen:

```
class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            UnderlineButton(
              label: 'Recent',
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            UnderlineButton(
              label: 'Top 50',
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            UnderlineButton(
              label: 'Festival',
              onTap: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://medium.com/vijay-r/neon-light-effect-flutter-23a36c341fe7 will help you,
For dynamic size Try setting mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min on the column and adding some spacing.